# How to calculate the average of each row in PowerBI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can i find the average of each row?

I need to calculate the average of category 1 to 5 for Location A and B and C and so on.

[image]

Problem 2: I need to calculate the of all columns in row 10

[image]

I tried average, averagea and average but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option-1:** You unpivot data and your category values will comes in row per category. Now you can easily calculate the average per location.

**Option-2:** do something very static like: (cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4+cat5)/5